# Coding 1 For Loop that calculates and prints the sum of all numbers less then and equal to user supplied number

Tags: python, for-loop

I have the loop down, and it prints all the numbers less than and equal to the input but I cant figure out how to add up all the numbers. (This is with a very small amount of knowledge of python I'm taking Coding 1 Classes in high school)

Heres what i have so far

```
    def sum():
        i = int(input("Give me a number "))
        for i in range(i):
            print(i + 1)
    sum()
```

This will print all the numbers I need.
Im trying to figure out how to add up all the numbers it will print but can't quite wrap my head around it.

Comment: If you wrap your code with ``` ``` it will render as code in your post and make it more readable.

Comment: At the top of the function, set a variable (you could call it `total`) to 0.  Each time through the loop, add `i` to it.

Answer (score 2):

`sum()` is a built-in Python function that takes an iterable. Best practice would say **not** to override this with your own definition.

`range(N)` *returns* an iterable up to that number. Adding one will include that number.

So combine these, and print the result, `print(sum(range(1 + int(input('enter a number: ')))))`

Answer (score 1):

As the fix of your approach was already given, let me give you another approach.

Learning programming is not only about learning the syntax, it's also about algorithms. Here, generating all numbers and summing them is not the most efficient way.

You can directly compute the result with one simple formula ([`sum(1->n) = (n*(n+1))/2`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF)), use it!

```
n = input('Give me a number ')
print((n*(n+1))//2)
```

Examples:

```
Give me a number 10
55

Give me a number 9876543210
48773052894436823655
```

Answer (score 0):

Also from someone still learning.

With your current code, I believe you could append the values into an empty list like this:

```
def summing():
  i = int(input("Give me a number "))
  empty = []

  for i in range(i + 1):
     print(i + 1)
     empty.append(i)


print(sum(empty))
```

Alternatively, you could also use a list comprehension, which is more efficient:

```
def summing():
  i = int(input("Give me a number "))
  empty = [i for i in range(i + 1)]


print(sum(empty))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a variable to store and add each increment in loop and change range to start from 1 to input+1 if you need to print each value:

```
def total():
    num = int(input("Give me a number "))
    result = 0
    for i in range(1,num+1):
        print(i)
        result += i
    print(result)

total()
```

Or use sum():

```
def total():
    num = int(input("Give me a number "))
    print(*(seq:=range(1,num+1)), sum(seq), sep='\n')

total()
```

Output:

```
# Give me a number 4
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
# 10
```